configuring agent and intent in Dialogflow es
i'm not able to configure the agent and intent. I'm only getting the 'create fallback intent' and not the 'welcome intent'. I'm setting the custom responses and user expression but getting nothing in 'Try it now' section.. what to do now?
Someone please help me with this.

Currently, based on your screenshot given you are in Mega agents which is a type of agent used for combining multiple of sub-agent into one. I recommend changing your agent type just for you to configure your agent and intents.
Try using a hello-dialoflow agent, from here you may be able to configure the agent and intent as you want.


Thanks sir it helped me a lot
